# How to make the svelte compiler throw an error when accessing an undefined property?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

Using Typescript,

```
enum People {
    Jhon = 'Jhon',
    Jane = 'Jane'
}
console.log(People.Mike)
```

In Angular, the above code would throw an error:

> Property 'Mike' does not exist on type 'typeof People'

But in svelte it compiles successfully with no errors, and prints "Undefined" in the console, which may cause unexpected bugs.

So how can I make the Svelte compiler throw an error in this case? Is this even a thing in Svelte?

I tried to play around with the tsconfig.json configurations but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the intended method of type checking Svelte components is by using the [`svelte-check` package](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/packages/svelte-check/README.md). This can e.g. be run as a build step or in watch mode during development.